# Регулярное выражение для парсинга лога в Logstash grok

Tags: регулярные-выражения, логирование, elasticsearch

Пытаюсь написать регулярное выражение фильтра logstash grok  для лога своего web приложения
Сам лог формата:

```
2015-12-02 14:5728,763 POST 1.1.1.1 627472 start_one windows 7 x64
```

Расшифровка:

> Дата метод адрес число функция система

С "нормальным" логом я справиться

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:date} %{WORD:method} %{IPV4:client} %{NUMBER:size} %{WORD:def} (?<VerOs>.*)
```

На выходе имеем

```
{
  "date": [
    "2015-12-02 14:5728,763"
  ],
  "method": [
    "POST"
  ],
  "client": [
    "1.1.1.1"
  ],
  "size": [
    "627472"
  ],
  "def": [
    "start_one"
  ],
  "VerOs": [
    "windows 7 x64"
  ]
}
```

А вот с логом, в котором есть ошибка или пустая переменная, не могу

лог с ошибкой:

```
2015-12-3 12:16:43,631 POST 2.2.2.2 637263 error=Bad request -
2015-12-3 12:16:43,631 POST 2.2.2.2 error=No found this address - -
2015-12-3 12:16:46,631 GET - - -
2015-12-3 12:16:46,631 POST 3.3.3.3 del -
```

Хотелось бы изменить имена переменных в поле где  встретилась ошибка на error а пустые поля (обозначенные символом "-") исключить из фильтрации

Хочу получить примерно такой результат. Могу и логирование в системе изменить

```
{
  "date": [
    "2015-12-02 14:5728,763"
  ],
  "method": [
    "POST"
  ],
  "client": [
    "1.1.1.1"
  ],
  "size": [
    "627472"
  ],
  "error": [
    "Bad request"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная проблема которую я вижу это, то что у тебя не фиксированный формат лога т.е. формат строки с ошибкой и без отличаются.

Есть два подхода к решению:

1. Поменять формат лога на едино образный когда каждый элемент на своем месте даже если отсутствует.

Например:

```
2015-12-02 14:57:28,763;POST;1.1.1.1;627472;start_one;windows 7 x64
2015-12-02 14:57:28,763;POST;1.1.1.2;;;;error=No found this address
```

2. Описать оба варианта и правила по которому их выбирать, [примеры](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/config-examples.html).